# JS jquery date calendar which displays localized date but sends ISO to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, calendar

I'm looking for a simple jQuery JS date calendar to gracefully degrade HTML5 date fields.

On latest versions of Chrome, a type=date field just renders a calendar localized to the current browser language. But the field value is set to the ISO date. So that the value sent to the server is always the ISO date. And when the field renders, it displays the localized date from the ISO value.

I would like just the same behavivor for Firefox/IE9 or >. Is there a out-of-the-box working jQuery/pure JS component for that?

Thanks.